# How to do distro-upgrade using Shell-AI?

Tags: upgrade

[Shell-AI (shai)](https://github.com/ricklamers/shell-ai) is a CLI utility that brings the power of natural language understanding to your command line.

I would like to use it to upgrade my OS ubuntu 20.04 as it is otherwise a daunting task.

What natural language commands will accomplish this task?

Comment: If it's a daunting task I'd reconsider my career choices. AI is far from perfect, and allowing any existing AI utilities to affect system configuration seems close to madness. I would consider the update *using* it far more daunting.

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.